# Using NSPredicate to filter an object and a key(that needs to be split)

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I have the following dictionary set up(Object, Key)

```
0, "10;0.75,0.75"
1, "0;2.25,2.25"
3, "1;3.5,2.0"
4, "1;4.5,3.0"
5, "2;6.0,5,0"
```

What I want to filter will be based on the object AND the key. The object is a NSNumber. The key is a string but i really don't want the entire string. I want to split the string separated by the semicolon and take the first index of the split which would yield the strings 10,0,1,1 or 2 depending on which object I was looking for.

As a specific example:

Are there any keys that are equal to @"1" with an object that is greater than 3.

In this case i should expect back YES since object 4 has a key that is equal to @"1", after i do the split.

I guess I was looking for a clever way to define a NSPredicate to do the split on the key separated by the semicolon and then filter(compare, etc) based on that. Let me know if you have any questions or need additional info.

Comment: If you can format the dictionary, that would be the easiest way to do the filtering.

Comment: You can use a predicate, but you need to write the comparison method yourself.

Comment: yeah i was wanting to define a predicate without doing the comparison. I already had my mind on something like Anupdas answered with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very naive implementation that I could think of

```
- (BOOL)hasKey:(NSString *)key withValueGreaterThan:(id)object{

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"10;0.75,0.75": @0,
                                 @"0;2.25,2.25" : @1,
                                 @"1;3.5,2.0"   : @3,
                                 @"1;4.5,3.0"   : @4,
                                 @"2;6.0,5,0"   : @5};


    NSPredicate *keyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@",key];

    NSArray *filteredKeys = [[dictionary allKeys]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:keyPredicate];

    for (NSString *k in filteredKeys) {

        NSNumber *value = dictionary[k];
        if (value>object) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Use

```
BOOL hasValue = [self hasKey:@"1;" withValueGreaterThan:@3];
```

Comment: This answer was written first and is about what I had already written but was wanting to define a predicate without writing the loop piece.

Comment: Correction - you also need to split the key before you can compare yes?Also i dont want to get all the keys just the ones greater than the object number. That would save me some iterations in the loop if my Dictionary was 100,000 items. yes? Maybe do the compare on the object (allKeysForObject(id)) instead of allKeys.

Comment: Well i guess there isnt an easy way to get allObjects like i thought so maybe you have to do it your way...unless I am missing a method? I've always wondered why they allow you to get allObjects.

Comment: @cspam There is no separation of key. The gotcha here is to include the semicolon, else if you give just '1' key '10' will also pass the test. When we check the dictionary, you already know the key and condition for equality. So there is no need for splitting key.

Comment: There seems to be an error  - what if key is 3 - it will grab all items starting with 3 - 30,300,31,etc.

Comment: yeah you are right @AndreiShender. You can do this:  NSPredicate *keyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@",[key]stringByAppendingFormat@";"]. this should give you just the number followed by the semicolon.

Comment: @AndreiShender I have specified that condition in my previous comment. Since the key formatting is not usual one, OP don't mind that little caveat I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Sample Code:

```
NSDictionary* dict = @{ @"10;0.75,0.75":@0,
                        @"0;2.25,2.25":@1,
                       @"1;3.5,2.0":@3,
                       @"1;4.5,3.0":@4,
                       @"2;6.0,5,0":@5};

__block NSString* foundKey = nil;
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* key, NSNumber* obj, BOOL *stop) {
    //here goes condition
    //get substr
    NSArray* arr = [key componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    int num = [[arr objectAtIndex:0]integerValue];
    if ((num == 1)&&([obj integerValue]>3)) {
        foundKey = key;
        stop = YES;
    }
}];
if (foundKey) {
    NSLog(@"%@:%@",foundKey,[dict objectForKey:foundKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following method:

```
-(BOOL)filterFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict keyEqual:(NSString*)key greaterthanObj:(NSString*)obj
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
    for (NSString *eachkey in allKeys) {
        NSString *trimmedKey = [self trimKeyuntill:@";" fromString:eachkey];
        NSString *trimmedValue = [dict objectForKey:eachkey];
        if ([trimmedKey isEqualToString:key] && [trimmedValue intValue] > [obj intValue]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;

}
```

call the above method with your dictionary like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10;0.75,0.75",@"0;2.25,2.25",@"1;3.5,2.0",@"1;4.5,3.0",@"2;6.0,5,0", nil]];
[self filterFromDictionary:dict keyEqual:@"1" greaterthanObj:@"3"]
```

I assumed all your objects are nsstrings. otherwise change the **intValue**